# set.seed() function influence into random in R

Tags: r, random, random-seed

Today i first met a `set.seed` function in R.
It's useful in same times, and i understand how to use it. But i have a small problem - how to choose a real good number as a first parameter in this function?

From that question a get another - how the first parameter from `set.seed()` function influence into random in R? Maybe if i understand the last, i will take the answer of first.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably need to start by reading [`? set.seed`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html).

Comment: (spam comment) http://benjaminlmoore.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/most-common-rng-seeds-r-github/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In a nutshell:**
By setting `set.seed()` you specify the starting-point for all "pseudo random number generators" that create the random numbers in `R`. See `?set.seed`

As computers are very deterministic there is nothing like a real "random number". 
Computers always have to use an algorithm to generate so called "pseudo random numbers".
These generators/algorithms work (very often) iterative so the next number is influenced by its predecessor. `set.seed()` defines the initial predecessor and thereby makes pseudo random numbers reproducible. Which number you choose is irrelevant in most cases.

(see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: I tend to use - and I'm not sure why - my birthday: `set.seed(310366)`. I think I read something somewhere where someone said they did it, and I thought it was a cute idea. So: use my birthday.